# Segfault on first attribution (classes in C++)

Tags: c++, class, oop, templates

I have this code and I keep getting segfault on the first attempt to do an attribution

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class type, int linha, int coluna>
class MetodoNw{

    private:
        type metodoNw[linha][coluna];
        int match, missmatch, gap;

    public:
        MetodoNw();
};

template <class type, int linha, int coluna>
MetodoNw <type,linha,coluna> :: MetodoNw(){
    match = 5;
    missmatch = -3;
    gap = -4;
}

int main(){
    cout << "######" << endl;
    MetodoNw<int,2000,2000> metodo1;
    return 0;
}
```

If I declare some variable like `int i;`, it works well. If I have something like `int i=0;`, then I get a segfault. Same with cout, printf and other functions. I just don't know what to do... Tried tutorials, books, gdb but got nothing.

NOTE: This is just a piece of the code, that's why it does nothing.

Comment: Stackoverflow, allocate the array on the heap (or better yet use `std::vector`).

Comment: You probably are getting a stack overflow. You're trying to allocate an `int[2000][2000]` on the stack, which likely requires ~16MB of space. Most stacks aren't that big.

Comment: segfaults occur because of wild pointers and undefined pointers - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault?scrlybrkr

Answer (score 2):

The segfault is probably due to the large array of size 2000x2000

I suggest using a [*`std::vector`*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) like following :

```
std::vector< std::vector<type> > metodoNw ;
```

and initialize it like :

```
template <class type, int linha, int coluna>
MetodoNw <type,linha,coluna> :: MetodoNw():
    metodoNw(linha, std::vector<type>(coluna)){
    match = 5;
    missmatch = -3;
    gap = -4;

}
```